# How to keep a blank row in Power Query when there's no data from the original worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I appended multiple power queries into one table because I am working with more than one worksheet. Please see my example image below. When I delete the data for Bob and Betty from the "Blueberries" worksheet it causes the power query results from the row "Lettuce" to move up into the row for "Blueberries". How do I prevent that from happening? I want the "Blueberries" row to remain blank when there is no data from that respective worksheet. My example image below:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYznW.jpg)

[image]

EDIT: Please ignore the values in column A; I put them in my example but they don't exist on my actual spreadsheet.

Here is the query code from @flexyourdata - thank you for answering my previous question! (note: I change  Name="data" to "dataApples", "dataBlueberries", "dataLettuce" for each sheet query):

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="data"]}[Content],

//remove blank rows
RemoveNulls = Table.SelectRows(Source,each [Assigned To] <> null)[[Assigned To],[#"Item #"],[#"Serial #"]],

//convert each record to a sub-list of a list
ListOfLists = List.Transform(Table.ToRecords(RemoveNulls),each Record.ToList(_)),

//combine the sub-lists into a single list of values
Combine = List.Combine(ListOfLists),

//convert the list into a one-column table
AsTable = Table.Transpose(Table.FromColumns({Combine})),

//the original column headers
Header = Table.ColumnNames(RemoveNulls),

//convert the column headers to repeats of the original
ChangeTableHeader = Table.TransformColumnNames(
                        AsTable,
                        each 
                            let 
                                num = Number.From(Text.Replace(_,"Column","")),
                                calc = Number.RoundDown((num - 1) / List.Count(Header)) + 1
                            in Header{Number.Mod(num-1,3)} & " " & Text.From(calc)
                    )
```

in
ChangeTableHeader

Comment: Those values in column A need to be part of the query, not typed into the sheet. 

Pls edit the question and include the query code.

Comment: lots of ifs (excel version/complexity of actual data/etc), but `textsplit(textjoin())` could be a simpler option.